# Remove folders from txt file in windows cmd

Tags: powershell, batch-file, text, replace, cmd

I have file with thousand lines like this.

```
x:/folder/folder/PN.xxx 
y:/folder/PN.xxx 
...
```

I need to make script for change this (for using in excel):

```
x;file.xxx
y;file.yyy
```

Best result for me is something this:

```
x;PN;x:/folder/folder/
y;PN;y:/folder/
```

I try to use easiest way in cmd:

```
D:\>powershell -Command "(gc serverPN.txt) -replace 'xxx', ';' | Out-File myFile.txt"
```

But I dont know, what is needet to write in XXX, when i want remove everything between /*/. Something like this can be close:"`\\[\D]*\\'`".

Thanks for help.

Comment: So, you want `drive_letter;file_name.extension`, regardless of the path between?

Comment: yes, I need remove paths. In best way have result: drive_letter;file_name.extension;path.

Comment: So what do you want: `x;file.xxx` or `x;PN;x:/folder/folder/` or `x;PN.xxx;x:/folder/folder/`? what does `file` stand for (it does not occur in the original lines)?

Comment: Sorry, File.xxx and Pn.xxx is the same. x;file.xxx will be good, but x;PN;x:/folder/folder/ will be better for next work in excel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supposing the lines are stored in `text_file.txt`, for a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) solution you need a `for /F` loop and the `~` modifiers for loop variable expansion (see also `for /?` for details):

```
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%L in ("text_file.txt") do (
    echo(%%~dL;%%~nxL;%%~dpL
)
```

This reaults in the following output with respect to the sample data in your question:

> ```
> x:;PN.xxx;x:/folder/folder/
> y:;PN.xxx;y:/folder/
> ```

If you want the pure file name without extension in the output, replace `%%~nxL` by `%%~nL`.

Answer (score 1):

In PowerShell try:

```
gc "serverPN.txt" | % { 
    get-item $_ | %{ 
        "$($_.PSDrive);$($_.Name);$($_.Directory)" | Out-File "myFile.txt" -Append 
    } 
}
```

Comment: I realy like your idea to retrieve the items and work with the objects. The only drawback is, that you need to be able to retrieve all that files

Answer (score 1):

This should be your requested regular expression: `:.*/` and you can replace it with a `;`:

```
powershell -Command "(gc serverPN.txt) -replace ':.*/', ';' | Out-File myFile.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$test = 'C:/test1/test2/test3/test4/testfile.xls'

$newfile =$test.Substring(0,2) + ';' + $test.Substring($test.LastIndexOf('/')+1,($test.Length-$test.LastIndexOf('/')-1))
```

Output :

```
C:;testfile.xls
```

Answer (score 0):

While it is not the beloved PowerShell, cmd could also produce the "best result".

```
C:>TYPE fi2.bat
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

FOR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%f IN (`TYPE fi2.txt`) DO (
    SET DRIVE=%%~df
    SET DRIVE=!DRIVE:~0,1!

    SET FILENAME=%%~nf

    SET DIRNAME=%%~pf
    SET DIRNAME=!DIRNAME:\=/!

    ECHO !DRIVE!;!FILENAME!;%%~df!DIRNAME!
)

EXIT /B 0

C:>CALL fi2.bat
x;PN;x:/folder/folder/
y;PN;y:/folder/
```